# Animated-selector causes crash on view initialization

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

My goal is to create a custom switch including animated transitions between checked and unchecked state.

I easily achieved a default state and my switch looks as expected in both states and it changes its look when its state is changed.

Problem arises when I attach animated-selector instead of regular one.

I'm gettting an error like this:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML
>   file line #10: Error inflating class android.widget.Switch
>
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/switch_track_animation_unchecked_checked.xml from
>   drawable resource ID #0x7f060072
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2640)
>
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/switch_track_animated_selector.xml from drawable resource
>   ID #0x7f060070

I can assure that I'm properly accessing those drawables etc.

I went through invalidate caches and restart, clean build, rebuild etc. and it won't work.

View sample

```
<Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector"
            android:track="@drawable/switch_track_animated_selector"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/switch2"/>
```

switch_track_animated_selector

```
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/checked"
          android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bckg_on"
          android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/unchecked"
          android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bckg_off"
          android:state_checked="false"/>

    <transition
            android:fromId="@+id/unchecked"
            android:toId="@+id/checked"
            android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_animation_unchecked_checked"/>

    <transition
            android:fromId="@+id/checked"
            android:toId="@+id/unchecked"
            android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_animation_checked_unchecked"/>
</animated-selector>
```

switch_bckg_on.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00B05A"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#00B05A" />
    <corners android:radius="180dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

switch_bckg_off.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F1F1F1"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#E0E0E0" />
    <corners android:radius="180dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

switch_track_animation_checked_unchecked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bckg_on">
    <target android:name="android:drawable">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor"
                    android:valueFrom="#A0A0A0"
                    android:valueTo="#1E9618"
                    android:valueType="intType" />
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

switch_track_animation_unchecked_checked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bckg_off">
    <target android:name="android:drawable">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor"
                    android:valueFrom="#A0A0A0"
                    android:valueTo="#1E9618"
                    android:valueType="intType"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

I also checked above approach using vector drawable instead of shape and I had the same result.
Example of vectors

ic_thumb_vector_off

```
<vector android:height="33dp" android:viewportHeight="300"
    android:viewportWidth="300" android:width="33dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:name="background_off" android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:fillType="nonZero"
        android:pathData="M149.926,149.926m-149.176,0a149.176,149.176 0,1 1,298.352 0a149.176,149.176 0,1 1,-298.352 0"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.1" android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="0.5"/>
    <path android:name="icon_off" android:fillColor="#9B9B9B" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M166.88,146.104C166.13,145.354 166.13,144.228 166.88,143.478L195.019,115.339C195.77,114.588 196.145,113.463 196.145,112.712C196.145,111.962 195.77,110.836 195.019,110.086L189.767,104.833C189.016,104.083 187.891,103.708 187.14,103.708C186.015,103.708 185.264,104.083 184.514,104.833L156.375,132.972C155.624,133.723 154.499,133.723 153.748,132.972L125.609,104.833C124.859,104.083 123.733,103.708 122.983,103.708C122.233,103.708 121.107,104.083 120.357,104.833L115.104,110.086C114.354,110.836 113.979,111.962 113.979,112.712C113.979,113.463 114.354,114.588 115.104,115.339L143.243,143.478C143.994,144.228 143.994,145.354 143.243,146.104L115.104,174.243C114.354,174.993 113.979,176.119 113.979,176.869C113.979,177.62 114.354,178.745 115.104,179.496L120.357,184.748C121.107,185.499 122.233,185.874 122.983,185.874C123.733,185.874 124.859,185.499 125.609,184.748L153.748,156.609C154.499,155.859 155.624,155.859 156.375,156.609L184.514,184.748C185.264,185.499 186.39,185.874 187.14,185.874C187.891,185.874 189.016,185.499 189.767,184.748L195.019,179.496C195.77,178.745 196.145,177.62 196.145,176.869C196.145,176.119 195.77,174.993 195.019,174.243L166.88,146.104Z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

ic_thumb_vector_on

```
<vector android:height="33dp" android:viewportHeight="302"
    android:viewportWidth="302" android:width="33dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:name="background_on" android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:fillType="nonZero"
        android:pathData="M151,151m-150.25,0a150.25,150.25 0,1 1,300.5 0a150.25,150.25 0,1 1,-300.5 0"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.1" android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="0.5"/>
    <path android:name="icon_on" android:fillColor="#00B05A" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M105.523,153.198C104.806,152.5 104.448,151.453 104.448,150.754C104.448,150.056 104.806,149.009 105.523,148.31L110.536,143.422C111.968,142.026 114.117,142.026 115.549,143.422L115.907,143.772L135.602,164.371C136.318,165.069 137.393,165.069 138.109,164.371L186.093,115.841L186.451,115.841C187.883,114.444 190.032,114.444 191.464,115.841L196.477,120.728C197.91,122.125 197.91,124.22 196.477,125.616L139.183,183.573C138.467,184.272 137.751,184.621 136.676,184.621C135.602,184.621 134.886,184.272 134.17,183.573L106.239,154.246L105.523,153.198Z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

Maybe I/m missing something in gradle file?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "...customswitch"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I expect this view to load and not to throw an error on view init.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `switch_track_animation_unchecked_checked.xml` and `switch_track_animation_checked_unchecked.xml` are animated `VectorDrawables`, and these animate static `VectorDrawable` states. You are trying to animate `ShapeDrawable`, and not `VectorDrawable` and that's what is causing the exception, I think.

You need to replace `switch_bckg_on.xml` and `switch_bckg_off.xml` with `<vector>...</vector>` implementations to animate them from within an `<animated-vector>...</animated-vector>` block.

Alternatively you could replace the AnimatedVectorDrawables with [`StateListAnimator`](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/statelistanimator/), although I'm not sure that will actually be able to do what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I had the same issue while using vector drawables. I'll update my question so you can see those vectors. It didn't help though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your *switch_track_animated_selector* does not have some *default* state without any id. You may try to add this state. This helped me in a similar situation